# Integration of $d^2x/dt^2$.

Tags: calculus

If,

$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -16x$

When $t= 0, v = 10$ and $x = 0$, where $x$ is displacement and $v$ is velocity.

How would I obtain an expression for the velocity and displacement at time t?

I am used to working with $dv/dt$, $vdv/dt$ and $d/dx[1/2v^2]$ and I'm not sure how to go about this question.

### My solution so far:

$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -16x$

$\dfrac{d^2x}{-16x} = dt^2$

This is where I get stuck, according to wolfram alpha the final solution will be trigonometric.

Comment: Have you ever solved linear differential equations of order 2? There is a general method doing so...

Comment: $x$ looks like the displacement; so integrate $\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -16x$ once to get velocity and twice to get displacement. (while taking into account the initial conditions obviously).

Comment: @K.Rmth It's not that simple, since you have a differential equation. Integration would work if you had $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -16t$.

Comment: @5xum, Why is that? Since you can integrate constant functions, why not integrate $-16x$ with respect to $t$?

Comment: @frabala Because you then get the equation $x' = -16\int x(t) dt$ which is just as hard to solve as the original one. And you cannot evaluate the integral if you do not have $x(t)$, but you need to evaluate it if you want to calculate $x(t)$, so you are stuck unless you attack the equation like it is a differential equation which it is.

Comment: Oh. OK . Now I see it. My bad. So this'll involve integrating factors and the like then?

Comment: Have you analysed the motion of a pendulum or of a weight on a spring in your studies?

Comment: We've glossed over SHM regarding springs

Comment: Well if you have studied simple harmonic motion at all, you might recognise the form of this equation.

Comment: I understand d^2x/dt^2 represents acceleration. I've seen it used to express acceleration. However, I have never seen it being used to solve a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since there seem to be some confusion, I write some more details of a solution.

Your differential equation can be written
$$
x''(t)+16x(t)=0.
$$
The characteristic polynomial is
$$
r^2+16=0,
$$
with solutions $r=\pm 4i$. Therefore, by the theorem on linear second order differential equations with constant coefficients,
$$
x(t)=A\cos 4t+B\sin 4t,
$$
for some constants $A$ and $B$. Now use the fact that $x(0)=0$ and $x'(0)=10$ to determine $A$ and $B$.

**Alternative way of solving the differential equation**

Multiply by $x'$, to get
$$
x''(t)x'(t)+16x'(t)x(t)=0.
$$
Now
$$
x''(t)x'(t)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(x'(t))^2\quad\text{and}\quad
x'(t)x(t)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}(x(t))^2
$$
and we conclude that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}((x'(t))^2+16x(t)^2)=0.
$$
Integrating from $0$ to $t$, we find that
$$
(x'(t))^2+16x(t)^2=(x'(0))^2+16x(0)^2=100.
$$
Thus,
$$
x'(t)=\pm\sqrt{100-16x(t)^2},
$$
where the plus has to be taken, since $x'(0)=10$. This is a separable differential equation,
$$
\frac{x'(t)}{\sqrt{100-16x(t)^2}}=1.
$$
Integrating from $0$ to $t$,
$$
\frac{1}{4}\arcsin(2x(t)/5)=t.
$$
Moving things around, we get
$$
x(t)=\frac{5}{2}\sin(4t).
$$

Comment: I'm a high school student and I haven't seen or heard of 'the theorem on linear second order differential equations.'

Comment: Then I wonder how they(?) think you should solve this? Do you have any idea from what is covered in the book/class at the moment?

Comment: We haven't touched on anything like this before. I'm just following what I'm used to seeing (i.e. separating the variables) then using straight forward differentiation.

Comment: I updated with a version that solves this differential equation using separation of variables.

Comment: I meant to say integration, sorry! Sorry, but your solution doesn't look familiar at all.

Comment: At what step does it not look familiar. If we write the first equation as $\frac{dv}{dt}=-16x$ and then say that we multiply by $v$ to get $v\frac{dv}{dt}=-16\frac{dx}{dt}x$, does that look more familiar? To get better help, I suggest that you make it more clear in the question on what you have met before, and what methods you actually know.

Answer (score 2):

Philip wrote :

$\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -16x$

$\dfrac{d^2x}{-16x} = dt^2$

This is a complete nonsens.

It is more important for Philip to understand why this is a nonsens, than to solve the equation.

That is the raison why I answer to him without even talking about the method of solving.

$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$ doesn't mean that $d^2x$ is devided by $dt^2$. This is a conventional way to say that the function $x(t)$ is differentiated two times successively.

So literally $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -16x$ means :
the second derivative of the function $x(t)$ is equal to minus 16 times the function $x(t)$ itself. 
There is no $d^2x$ nor $dt^2$ in this sentense, so you are not allowed to mutiply or divide by one of these terms which have no meaning when taken independently.

Comment: I somehow agree with you that it is more important to understand the error and why it is not allowed to do like that (+1 for that). Nevertheless, I also think that a solution, or a hint of a solution should be present to Philip once he tells more about what methods he has met.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way of doing this (write $\frac {dx}{dt}=x'; \frac {d^2x}{dt^2}=x''$) by separating variables. I don't know whether you will be familiar with all the ideas, but they may well become familiar.

With the equation $\frac {dx}{dt}=ax$ separating the variables gives $\int\frac {dx}x=\int a dt$ so that $\ln x=at+c$ and raising to the power $e$ with $C=e^c$ gives $x=Ce^{at}$.

Now, with $x''=-a^2x$ write $y=x'+aix$ and $z=x'-aix$ where $i$ is a square root of $-1$.

Then $$y'=x''+aix'=-a^2x+aix'=ai(aix+x')=aiy$$ so we have $y=Ce^{ait}$ and in a similar way $z=De^{-ait}$

Now compute $y'-z'=2aix=Ce^{ait}+De^{-ait}$ and finally dividing through by $2ai$ we have $x=Ae^{ait}+Be^{-ait}$

Then we can use $e^{\pm ait}=\cos at \pm i \sin at$ and to transform this into the form $x=E\cos at+ F\sin at$

---

For the equation $$x''+ax'+bx=0$$ let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of $u^2-au+b=0$ so that $a=-(\alpha+\beta)$ and $b=\alpha\beta$ then you will find that $y=x'-\alpha x$ and $z=x'-\beta x$ allow you to separate variables e.g. $$0=x''-(\alpha+\beta)x'+\alpha\beta x=(x''-\alpha x')-\beta (x'-\alpha x)=y'-\beta y$$ so that $y=Ce^{\beta t}$ and similarly $z=De^{\alpha t}$ then $y-z=(\beta-\alpha)x=Ce^{\alpha t}+De^{\beta t}$ and if $\beta \neq \alpha$ then $x=Ae^{\alpha t}+Be^{\beta t}$

It is this form which you will find yourself using if you do much more work of second order differential equations of this kind - you don't have to do all the workings every time, just solve the quadratic and plug in the roots.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

As noted in the comments there is a general method to solve second order linear  differential equations, that you can find on any book about differential equations. But this case is very simple.

I'm pretty sure that you know that a function as: $ f(t)=\sin (at)$ has first derivative $f'(t)=a \cos (at)$ and second derivative: $ f''(t)= -a^2\sin (at)=-a^2 f(t)$. And we have the same for a function $g(t)=\cos(at)$, that gives:$ g''(t)= -a^2\cos (at)=-a^2 g(t)$.

Since you have a linear equation a solution is linear combination of these particular solutions: $ x(t)= C_1 f(t)+C_2 g(t)$

Can you elaborate from this and find the two cosntants from the initial conditions?